# Applying changes in HTML for all elements at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html which contains many (80) small boxes with some info. All these boxes are displayed in grid.

All these boxes and tags are identical just Text is different inside each block. Each box has lets say 3 values: name, email and mobile number.

I want to swap the position of email and mobile number. It will take so much time to do manually. Is there any way or automatic process or tool by which I can just change one block and it will be applied to all others?

Code of boxes:

```
  <div class="row gutters-40">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <h4 class="service__title">Private limited Registration</h4>
          <h2 style="font-weight: bold; color: purple; font-family: sans-serif;"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 7500 Rs</h2>
           <h5 class="doctype">Documents Required</h5>
           <div class="docs">
             <ul>
               <li>Aadhar card & Pancard of Directors</li>
               <li>Photo of Directors</li>
               <li>Address Proof of Directors</li>
               <li>Address Proof of Company address</li>
              <li>Qualification & occupation of directors</li>
              <li>Bank statement of Directors</li>
             </ul>
           </div><!--docs ends here-->
           <div class="price_time">
            <p class="service__paragraph" align="left" id="price"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Know More</p> 
           </div>
        </div><!--Thumbnail ends here-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <h4 class="service__title">limited Liability partnership</h4>
           <h5 class="doctype">Documents Required</h5>
           <div class="docs">
             <ul>
               <li>Aadhar card of Directors</li>
               <li>PAN Card of Directors</li>
               <li>Passport size photo of Directors</li>
               <li>Residential address proof of Director</li>
               <li>Registered Office address proof</li>
               <li>Appointment of auditor (ADT-1)</li>
             </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="price_time">
            <p class="service__paragraph" align="left" id="price"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 7199</p> 
            <p class="service__paragraph" align="right" id="days"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  10-15 days</p>   
           </div>
        </div><!--Thumbnail ends -->
      </div><!--box ends-->
  </div> <!--row ends-->
```

As you can see my price is in last `div` inside `p tag`. I want it above `h5 tag`.

I have almost 80 such boxes. With multicursor and moving line up it will still take time.
I thought find and replace with regex can work but I can't evaluate how to do that. There is `div class = docs` is between these two elements which I want to swap, so I haven't figured out should such regex look like.

Comment: If they're formatted consistently, you should be able to do it with a regexp replacement in your IDE.

Comment: In modern IDEs you can use combination of features - multicusor and moving line up/down

Comment: added code. can you tell how can I use regex for replacement.

Comment: a side note: you shouldn't use `id="price"` if you have multiple boxes (so that you have mutliple duplicated ids), use class instead (this can be easily fixed with "replace all")

Comment: do you want the whole block `<div class="price_time">` to be above `<h5 class="doctype">Documents Required</h5>`? Or is it only `<p class="service__paragraph" align="left" id="price"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 7199</p>` that you want to move?

Comment: @YakovL so I should replace all id = "price" to class = "price" right. I only want `<p class="service__paragraph" align="left" id="price"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 7199</p>` to move. and want to delete the remaining div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess this is somewhat too custom task to find an out-of-box tool, so I'd suggest to write simple one of your own. Here's an outline:

1. open you page in browser
2. open dev tools Console, run a script to modify html
3. open dev tools Elements, copy the modified html bit
4. substitute the boxes part of html in your page with the modified one

if your html is modified also by some other JS, in step 1. use instead a dedicated html containing just the piece that's of interest.

Now, the script should do the following:

1. find all the boxes (`document.querySelectorAll`)
2. for each of them, do the necessary operations with elements, like

   ```
   ​ const elementToMove = ...
   ​ const destinationElement = ...
   ​ destinationElement.appendChild(elementToMove)
   ​ const elementToRemove = ...
   ​ elementToRemove.remove()
   ```